# How to get related field in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have these related models:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
...

class ForumFront(models.Model):
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum, default=None)
    headline = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=None)
    topic_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'd like to get `topic_count` and `post_count` fields on a template that renders `forum` objects. How best can I achieve this?

I tried different tags like {{forum.topic_count}} but they display nothing.

Comment: topic_count and post_count are attributes of ForumFront. Each Forum object has *many* ForumFront objects, so therefore many topic_count and post_count values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is which `ForumFront` you want to show. Could be many `ForumFront` associated to a `Forum` object since it's a `ForeignKey`.

You could call `{{ forum.forumfront_set.all }}` and you would get all the `ForumFront` objects related to `{{ forum }}`.

You could display them like this:

```
{{ forum }}
<ul>
{% for f_f in forum.forumfront_set.all %}
    <li>{{ f_f.topic_count }}, {{ f_f.post_count }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. However, since there is only one `ForumFront` per `Forum`,  I just change the relationship to `forum = models.OneToOneField(Forum, default=None)` and now can catch the forumfronts in template simply using `{{forum.forumfront.topic_count}}`

Comment: @Jand Yes, a `OneToOne` relatioship does not map to `_set`.